# Is this structure recommended for test files in java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, inner-classes, file-structure

I'm new in the unit tests world for java. I'm trying to find the best files structure to keep my tests files organized. This is my current test files structure:

[image]

Inside **FileUtilities** and **GlobalUtilities** there are several functions. Inside **TestFileUtilities** and **TestGlobalUtilities** there are multiple classes inside global class; in summary, the number of nested classes inside of test file depends of the number of functions in **FileUtilities** or **GlobalUtilities**. Look what I'm talking about:

**Ex**: TestGlobalUtilities
[image]

I'm able to run all tests of a file using @RunWith(Enclosed.class), implemented by JUnit4.

So, here it's my main question. Is this a correct way to do it? I'm trying to do it using the most organized way. If this is not the best way to do it, what do you recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: the inner classes should not be needed, just have *one* setUp() and tearDown() and N test methods.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302. So, using TestFileUtilities as an example, do you recommend to create individual test file for each function in FileUtilities instead TestFileUtilities?

Comment: no, (one file, one setUp(), one tearDown(), N test methods) for each class / unit (whatever that means to you) you want to test.